# How to detect if tab key is pressed on listbox leave

Tags: c#, listbox, windows

I am developing an windows application.
In that application i have a list box control on one form.Now i need to detect if user presses tab key or Shift+tab key.how can i detect this on list box leave event.

Comment: Please post your code that you have written to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `KeyEventArgs` to detect what key has been pressed. But assuming that when a user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> the control loses focus you can just listen on the `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyPress` and check if the pressed items are <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

---

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    { 
        //Check for Tab key
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
        {
           //Do something
        }
        //Check for the Shift Key as well
        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
            //Other stuff to do
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some people say that tab does not get detected. Does this code work for you?

Comment: Tab is not getting detected. The event KeyDown is not getting called at all when Tab is being pressed.